# Does Mercurial have a template to capture output of "hg grep"?

Tags: grep, mercurial

I was searching for a change that included "foreach" so I used this Mercurial command:

```
$ hg grep -r "user(mjh) & public() & date(-30)" --diff -i foreach
```

and it does return the hits where "foreach" was added and removed.

However, I'd like to know the actual commit hashes too.  If I add a template:

```
$ hg grep ... -T '{date|shortdate}\n{node|short}\n{desc|firstline}\n\n'
```

then I get the commit hash and description as expected, but then I don't see the changed files listed.

Is there a template to capture the output of `hg grep`?  The `{files}` template lists the files associated with a commit, but that's not the actual grep output.  Is there an iterable template keyword available for the grep results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Please, re-read carefully `hg help grep -v` (-v is important option), note the following part (new and *unexpected for me* also)

> The following keywords are supported in addition to the common
> template
> keywords and functions. See also 'hg help templates'.
>
> ```
> change        String. Character denoting insertion "+" or removal "-".
>               Available if "--diff" is specified.
> lineno        Integer. Line number of the match.
> path          String. Repository-absolute path of the file.
> texts         List of text chunks.
> ```

After it you'll be able to repeat (so-so, because some details will differ slightly) default output of grep in you template

`>hg grep --diff -i -r 1166 to_try`
[image: Default grep]

`>hg grep --diff -i -r 1166 -T "{path}:{rev}:{change}:{texts}\n" to_try`

```
hggit/compat.py:1166:-:    for args in parameters_to_try:
hggit/compat.py:1166:+:    for (args, kwargs) in parameters_to_try:
```

and after replacing `{rev}` by `{node|short}`

```
>hg grep --diff -i -r 1166 -T "{path}:{node|short}:{change}:{texts}\n" to_try
hggit/compat.py:f6cef55e6aeb:-:    for args in parameters_to_try:
hggit/compat.py:f6cef55e6aeb:+:    for (args, kwargs) in parameters_to_try:
```